# skip 1st value of loop

Tags: php, loops

skip 1st value of loop. i'm trying getting youtube video search data from api with php in loop a got 2 video i want show only 2nd one and skip 1st one.

```
$grab=grabe('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='.$key.'&part=snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=2&q='.$q.'');
$json = json_decode($grab);
foreach ($json->items as $sam){
    $link= $sam->id->videoId;
```

i got '.$link.' 2 video , bout i want show 2nd video skip 1st 1 how it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code. Add one increment variable. And check that varaible

```
    $i =0;
    foreach ($json->items as $sam){
    if($i == 0)
    {
       $i++;
       continue;
    }

    $link= $sam->id->videoId;
```

Comment: after apply your code all video gone hide dear 1 need just skip 1st one then show next 9-10 video

Comment: have you added `$i++;`??

Comment: yeas dear i put $i =0;
        foreach ($json->items as $sam){
        if($i == 0)
        continue;
        $i++;
        $link= $sam->id->videoId;

Comment: check edited answer@AnanyaSharma

Comment: stil no luck dear $i =0;
        foreach ($json->items as $sam){
        
        if($i == 0)
        continue;
        $i++;
        
        
        $link= $sam->id->videoId;

Comment: I cant see any change in your code. I have updated code see in answer `if($i == 0)
    {
       $i++;
       continue;
    }`

Comment: thanks it working very fine now